# Почему не работает SimpleSearch?

Tags: modx, поиск

Есть сайт с поддоменами (возможно в этом и загвоздка) на modx формата msk.site.ru

По гайду установила SimpleSearch, создала страницу с результатами поиска:

```
[[!SimpleSearch]]
```

А на страницу блога, где должен быть сам поиск вставила (id 39 для примера, его я точно правильно вписываю так как уже делала формы поиска, но тут в чем-то проблема)

```
[[!SimpleSearchForm? &landing=`39`]]
```

И эта страница блога при открытии пишет

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'modX' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /var/www/u1111/data/www/msk.site.ru/core/components/simplesearch/src/SimpleSearch.php on line 16
```

При этом вот первые строчки этого файла (ничего не меняла, все стандартное)

```
<?php
namespace SimpleSearch;

use MODX\Revolution\modX;
use MODX\Revolution\modChunk;
use SimpleSearch\Driver\SimpleSearchDriver;

/**
 * The base class for SimpleSearch
 *
 * @package
 */
class SimpleSearch
{
/** @var modX $modx */
public modX $modx;
/** @var array $config */
public array $config = array();
/** @var string $searchString */
public string $searchString = '';
/** @var array $searchArray */
public array $searchArray = array();
/** @var int $searchResultsCount */
public int $searchResultsCount = 0;
/* @var string $ids */
public string $ids = '';
/** @var array $docs */
public array $docs = array();
/** @var array $chunks */
public array $chunks = array();
/** @var SimpleSearchDriver $driver */
public SimpleSearchDriver $driver;
/** @var SiHooks $postHooks */
public SiHooks $postHooks;
/** @var array $response */
public array $response = array();
```

Версия php 7.4, проверила, все должно работать по логике. Но не работает))

Пробовала менять саму форму в чанке SimpleSearch, никаких результатов не дало так как она и из коробки должна работать.

Jquery cdn добавила на страницу блога (вдруг в этом проблема), тоже 0 реакции

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Какая версия MODX и SimpleSearch?

Comment: @AntonTarasov modx 3.0.1-pl, simplesearch 3.0.0-alpha